# How to get bean id within factory method?

Tags: spring

Configuration

```
<bean id="carFactory" class="CarFactory" />
<bean id="ford" factory-bean="carFactory" factory-method="createCar"/>
```

Code:

```
public class CarFactory implements BeanNameAware {

    public String beanName;

    @Override public void setBeanName(String name) { beanName = name;}

    public Car createCar() {
        System.out.println(beanName); // prints carFactory
        return new Car();
    } 
}
```

How to print out *ford* ?

Comment: You won't be able to do that, only from within the `Car` if that would also implement `BeanNameAware`.

Comment: What a pity! Please answer as regular answer to give me chance to accept. BTW, in my case I need car name in factory method because it has impact on `createCar` algorithm.

Comment: See the answer by @reos you can use a factory method which takes 1 or more arguments and pass in the arguments using the `constructor-arg` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reos' solution is working, but I cannot accept duplication so I applied other solution

Configuration

```
<bean id="carFactory" class="CarFactory" />
<bean id="ford" class="CarProducer"/>
```

Code

```
public class CarProducer extends AbstractFactoryBean<Car> implements BeanNameAware {
    public String carName;

    @Override public void setBeanName(String name) { carName= name;}

    @Autowired private CarFactory factory;

    @Override protected Car createInstance() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(carName); // prints ford
        return factory.createCar(carName);
    }
    (...)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

factory-method is used to create an object, it replace the constructor call. When yo tell Spring factory-method="createCar" you're telling that it needs to call createCar in order to create the bean ford.

createCar method prints the name of the car but the properties are not been set already so it should be printing null.

I would recommend you to use constructor-arg in order to pass arguments to the createCar method.

```
<bean id="ford" factory-bean="carFactory" factory-method="createCar">
    <constructor-arg value="ford"/>
</bean>
```

And

```
public Car createCar(String beanName) {
    System.out.println(beanName); // prints carFactory
    return new Car();
}
```

Comment: It will work but 'ford' is used twice. In my project I have sever dozen cars. I would rather get fired that tell my team they have to write each mark two times.

Comment: hmmm, I don't undertand why you say the ford is used twice.

Comment: id="**ford**" ... value="**ford**". My case: Legacy code depends on bean id, I want keep it unchanged. I may simplify my code, because bean id can be mapped directly to filename. So I want read bean id (car id) in car factory But I don't want to repeat twice ford, toyota, etc.